# How do I render the react components dynamically from imported module?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-router

I am trying to render the React components dynamically based on the routes that are given in the URL.

canvas/index.tsx

```
export { default as CardGroup } from "./cards.example";
```

src/App.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import {
  useParams
} from "react-router-dom";
import * as Canvas from "./canvas";


const App: React.FC = () => {
    const params = useParams();
    const widgetName = (params.widgetName ?? '';
      return (
      <div className = "App" > 
      {< Canvas[widgetName] / >} // error here
      </div>
      );
    };

export default App;
```

I am not able to render the widget. It give me the following error.

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'typeof import("/Users/mypc/Code/atoms/src/canvas/index")'.
```

No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'typeof import("/Users/mypc/Code/atoms/src/canvas/index")'.

[image]

Comment: If you use webpack or some other bundler, you can leverage the `import()` syntax exactly for this purpose. Also check `React.lazy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Canvas[widgetName]` isn't a valid `React` component. Compute the component value first as a local variable and then render it as `JSX`.

I suggest creating a local `CanvasMap` object so you can type it correctly for what is imported. You are creating a lookup object that uses string type keys and returns the `React.FC` component.

Example:

```
import React from "react";
import * as Canvas from "./canvas";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const CanvasMap: { [K: string]: React.FC<{}> } = {
  ...Canvas
};

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const { widgetName } = useParams();
  const CanvasComponent = CanvasMap[widgetName ?? "NotFound"];
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <CanvasComponent />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error. I think there is some type casting that needs to happen.

Comment: @GhostChat Does that error happen to have a code stacktrace accompanying it at all?

Comment: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'typeof import("/Users/mypc/Code/atoms/src/canvas/index")'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'typeof import("/Users/mypc/Code/atoms/src/canvas/index")'

Comment: @GhostChat For something like this it might be easier for use to help if you are able to create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) that reproduces the issue that we can inspect and debug live.

Comment: here it is - https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-heisenberg-qecon8?file=/src/canvas/index.tsx

Comment: @GhostChat The code in the sandbox appears to be working to me. I had to comment out the CSS file imports to get it to compile, but navigating to `"/CardGroup"` renders that component.

Comment: Can you please check now? I added the tsconfig.json file. It was previously not getting the ts rules I wanted. Thanks

Comment: @GhostChat Sorry, I don't see any errors running the sandbox on my end. The `"/CardGroup"` and `"/NotFound"` routes load without issue.

Comment: try opening tsconfig.json and then navigate to App.tsx. I think you will then see the error. Please let me know if you don't see the error. Thanks a lot for taking interest in this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247094/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-ghost-chat).